# Hibernate query targetting a relation table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm using Hibernate to model 2 tables joined by a relation table with internal variables like this:

// Clinic.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clinic")
public class Clinic
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.clinic", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ClinicDoctor> clinicDoctors = new HashSet<ClinicDoctor>(0);

    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Set<ClinicDoctor> getClinicDoctors()
    {
        return clinicDoctors;
    }

    public void setClinicDoctors(Set<ClinicDoctor> clinicDoctors)
    {
        this.clinicDoctors = clinicDoctors;
    }
}
```

// Doctor.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "doctor")
public class Doctor
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.doctor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ClinicDoctor> clinicDoctors = new HashSet<ClinicDoctor>(0);

    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Set<ClinicDoctor> getClinicDoctors()
    {
        return clinicDoctors;
    }

    public void setClinicDoctors(Set<ClinicDoctor> clinicDoctors)
    {
        this.clinicDoctors = clinicDoctors;
    }
}
```

// ClinicDoctor

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clinic_doctor")
@AssociationOverrides({ @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.clinic", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "clinic")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.doctor", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "doctor")) })
public class ClinicDoctor
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private ClinicDoctorId pk = new ClinicDoctorId();

    @Column(name = "attendingHours")
    private String attendingHours;

    public ClinicDoctorId getPk()
    {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(ClinicDoctorId pk)
    {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    public String getAttendingHours()
    {
        return attendingHours;
    }

    public void setAttendingHours(String attendingHours)
    {
        this.attendingHours = attendingHours;
    }

    // Equals & HashCode
}
```

// ClinicDoctorId

```
public class ClinicDoctorId implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5880105185191860784L;

    @ManyToOne
    private Clinic clinic;

    @ManyToOne
    private Doctor doctor;

    public Clinic getClinic()
    {
        return clinic;
    }

    public void setClinic(Clinic clinic)
    {
        this.clinic = clinic;
    }

    public Doctor getDoctor()
    {
        return doctor;
    }

    public void setDoctor(Doctor doctor)
    {
        this.doctor = doctor;
    }

    // Equals & HashCode
}
```

I want to list all relations where the name of the clinic is 'X'. My best attempt so far is this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ClinicDoctor.class);
criteria.createAlias("pk.clinic", "clinic").add(Restrictions.eq("clinic.name", "X"));
res = new ArrayList<>(criteria.list());
```

This, however, results in the following Hibernate query and error:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        this_.clinic as clinic2_1_0_,
        this_.doctor as doctor3_1_0_,
        this_.attendingHours as attendin1_1_0_ 
    from
        clinic_doctor this_ 
    where
        clinic1_.name=?

ERROR: Unknown column 'clinic1_.name' in 'where clause'
```

I honestly have no idea why this is wrong. I believe to have done this before, but somewhere there's something I just can't see (or understand) that prevents this query from working. Can somebody give me a hand with this?

EDIT: As suggested below, I tried this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT cd FROM ClinicDoctor cd WHERE cd.doctor.name = :docname");
query.setParameter("docname", X);
```

and it works perfectly. However, I'd prefer a Criteria based answer, or at least an explanation as to why my initial query doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing i see is

```
where
        clinic1_.name=?
```

while you said in your question :

> I want to list all relations where the name of the doctor is 'X'.

so your query is trying to feching relations where the name of the **clinic** is 'X'

if you wish the first one try this out :

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT cd FROM ClinicDoctor cd WHERE cd.doctor.name = :docname");
query.setParameter("docname", X);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. You're correct: I meant "all relations where the name of the clinic is 'X'". I've edited my question. However, I've tried your suggestion, and a new error appears: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: doctor of: com.example.objects.ClinicDoctor [SELECT cd FROM com.example.objects.ClinicDoctor cd WHERE cd.doctor.name = :docname]

Comment: OK, I've tried changing "cd.doctor.name" for "cd.pk.doctor.name", and now it works perfectly. I'm tempted to mark this as the correct answer, but I'd prefer a solution based on Criteria. If none appear, I'll mark this answer as correct.

Comment: try an other name of alias : criteria.createAlias("pk.clinic", "c").add(Restrictions.eq("c.name", "X"));

Comment: Since nobody else has come up with a solution using Criteria, I'm accepting your answer... and changing all my workflow to HQL queries ;) Thanks, man.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to answer you. Yes, that was one of the initial things that I tried, but no luck there.